# Factory method with different method signature

Tags: c#, architecture, factory-pattern

I have three shipping carriers and as per user selection I want to generate the label. I am planning to implement Factory pattern for this but there is little confusion where I need help to take proper route.

Here are the details

```
public interface IShipper
{
    string GenerateLabel(Address FromAddress, Address ToAddress);
}
public class USPS : IShipper
{
    public string GenerateLabel(Address FromAddress, Address ToAddress)
    {
        //GET USPS LABEL FOR PROVIDED ADDRESSES
    }
}
public class UPS : IShipper
{
    public string GenerateLabel(Address FromAddress, Address ToAddress)
    {
        //GET UPS LABEL FOR PROVIDED ADDRESSES
    }
}
```

Here is the confusion. We have third shipping company which provides extra option of outbound. Customer may choose it or not.

```
public class OutBundShipper
{
    public string GenerateLabel(Address FromAddress, Address ToAddress, bool HasOutbound)
    {
//GET OutBundShipper LABEL FOR PROVIDED ADDRESSES
    }
}
```

With this information I want to know what will be better approach

- For all classes add HasOutBound parameter to GenerateLabel method. This way it will be consistent and with the interface it will work.
- Should I add overloaded method in the interface and throw not implemented exception in USPS and UPS classes?
- Any other better approach?

Comment: You haven't indicated why you plan to use the factory-pattern; this would be useful in helping to provide an optimum solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you just pass this into your factory method:

```
public IShipper GetShipper(ShipperType type, bool hasOutbound) {
     switch (type) {
          case USPS:
             return new USPS();
          ....
          case Outbound:                  
             return new OutboundShipper(hasOutbound)
     }
}
```

And use your factory method as before.

Not entirely sure if this is what you need - I don't know what 'hasoutbound' might signify and if you need to print multiple labels per instantiated shipper class, then this will not work.

---

Alternatively to that, rather than adding this boolean property directly to the method signature, I would suggest that you amend it to pass in an 'options' class:

```
string GenerateLabel(Address FromAddress, Address ToAddress, LabelOptions options);
```

This means that if you find further shippers with different parameter requirements, you can make amendments to the passed options class without having to update all the calling points.